# reasignar valor a cadena

Tags: c, array

Tengo esta asignación a una cadena:

```
unsigned char cadena[] = {154,162,162,145,'\0'};
```

Que es `"hola"`, pero en decimal.

¿Cómo puedo volver a asignar otro valor en decimal a la misma variable llamada cadena en este caso?

`strcpy` no sirve porque su parámetro es `char*`

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: strcpy si funciona porque los arreglos decan a punteros al usarse en una expresión. Traducción: Una variable char[] pasa a ser char* cuando se la pasas a strcpy.

Comment: y como hago esa asignacion? no entiendo como, me dice: c:\mingw\include\string.h:79:40: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: Es que quieres pasarle el parametro como un arreglo de enteros aun????

Comment: Esos no son decimales, es codigo ASCII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me contesto a mí mismo:
No se puede en decimal, sólo en octal o hexadecimal:

```
strcpy(cadena, "\xa2\xa5\xab\x95\x9b\x93");
```

Answer (score 1):

En base a los comentarios:

> Pero la dimension del nuevo arreglo difiere del primero??? – Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas
>
> si, puede ser {2,2,2,2,'\0'}; el nuevo valor como {24,22,23,54,43,23'\0'}; – Alberto Figueroa

Ya te aviso que cuidado con exceder el tamaño inicial.

Ante esta declaración:

```
unsigned char cadena[] = {154,162,162,145,'\0'};
```

El programa reserva 5 bytes para `cadena`. El resto de la memoria quedará a disposición de otras variables, luego si excedes ese límite de 5 bytes acabarás pisando el valor de otras variables y el programa podrá comportarse de forma errática.

Si tu idea es tener un array de tamaño variable tienes que recurrir a la memoria dinámica. Para solicitar memoria puedes usar `malloc`, pero para modificar el tamaño de dicha asignación hay que recurrir a `realloc`. `realloc` también puede usarse para hacer la reserva inicial de memoria, por lo que queda en tu mano elegir el mecanismo que mejor se adecúe a tus necesidades:

```
unsigned char *ptr = 0;
size_t max_size;

max_size = 10;
unsigned char* ptr2 = (unsigned char*)realloc(ptrmax_size*sizeof(unsigned char));
if( 0 == ptr2 )
{
  /* Error al solicitar memoria */
}

ptr = ptr2;
```

Nota que la reasignación de memoria puede fallar así que no está de más verificar el puntero que te devuelve `realloc`.

Después de esto ya puedes copiar los datos en la memoria como bien has indicado en tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Con strcpy si puedes cambiar el valor a un arreglo de char ya que pasa como puntero, solo tienes que castearlo a (char*) porque lo tienes como unsigned.

```
unsigned char cadena[] = {154,162,162,145,'\0'};
strcpy((char*)cadena, "Hello World!");
std::cout << "Probando: " << cadena << endl;
```

Comment: mmm, pero lo que quería era asignar valores decimales, no el "hello World!", de unsigned char cadena[] = {154,162,162,145,'\0'}; a vovler a asignar a cadena pero con otros valores en decimal.

Comment: Perdon, {154,162,162,145,'\0'}; no es "hola", aunque no importa, quiero reasignar despues de la asignación en la declaración otro valor, para no declarar otra variable, por ejemplo {2,2,2,2,'\0'};

Comment: Pero la dimension del nuevo arreglo difiere del primero???

Comment: si, puede ser {2,2,2,2,'\0'}; el nuevo valor como {24,22,23,54,43,23'\0'};

Comment: Quiere decir que igual o mayor que el inicial no???

Comment: Respondeme esto para editar mi respuesta con una nueva solucion

Comment: o menor, cualquier otro valor